# Django static files not being served by amazon s3 even though all the instructions have been strictly followed

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

This is my first time ever on this platform, so please don't mind me if I am breaching any rules. I just finished building my first django project and I am using an amazon s3 bucket to serve media and static files. I have deployed the app onto heroku but static and media files are not being loaded. When I inspect the page, I see that it is throwing a 403 error. All the policies of my bucket have been set as prescribed in the documentation. below is a picture of my relevant  setting.py

[settings .py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Rj27.png)

Comment: I have the following line of code that is also relevant to the question: django_heroku.settings(locals(), staticfiles=False)

Comment: please don't your code as image.

Comment: Also, you'll need to show your actual bucket policies; "set as prescribed in the documentation" isn't sufficient. And it would be helpful to show an actual request, with response (you can use developer mode in your browser to see the request). And, as *Long Luong* said, edit your question and post this information in code tags, _not_ as an image (nobody is going to click your link).